# MySQL return total COUNT of each value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a table of jobseekers
with three columns

```
JOBSEEKER ID, EMPLOYER ID, HIRING STATUS
```

Each jobseeker could have different hiring
status for each employer depending on the interview.
Now I want to return the
COUNT of each total HIRING STATUS
But it should only count the jobseeker's
highest hiring status.

Say that John was 
ranked as QUALIFIED by employer 1
and HIRED by employer 2
John will only be counted under the highest
hiring status he got which is HIRED by employer 2
and must not be counted under QUALIFIED.

```
HIRED: 1
QUALIFIED: 0
NEAR HIRED: 0
NOT QUALIFIED: 0
```

Here is my table

```
| Jobseeker Id | Employer Id | hstatus_id       |
|--------------|-------------|------------------|
|       1      | 2           | 1(Hired)         |
|       2      | 3           | 1(Hired)         |
|       2      | 4           | 3(Near Hire)     |
|       3      | 4           | 4(Not Qualified) |
|       1      | 2           | 2(Qualified)     |
|       3      | 3           | 1(Hired)         |
|       4      | 2           | 3(Near Hire)     |
```

and the result I want is

```
| Hiring Status | COUNT |
|---------------|-------|
|     Hired     | 3     |
|   Qualified   | 0     |
|   Near Hire   | 1     |
| Not Qualified | 0     |
```

Thank you, sorry for bad English.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what the data actually looks like.  Are the statuses numbers, strings, or strings that start with numbers?

Comment: Is there a table containing the statuses Hired, Qualified, Near Hire and Not Qualified?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The Statuses are actually status IDs from another table named "hStatus_table"

Comment: @forpas Yes, hiring status is a foreign key linked to another table named "hStatus_table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a LEFT join of the table `hStatus_table` to a query that returns the minimum integer `hiringstatus` of each `jobseekerid`:

```
select s.hiringstatus, count(t.jobseekerid) counter
from hStatus_table s
left join (
  select jobseekerid, min(hstatus_id) hstatus_id
  from tablename
  group by jobseekerid
) t on t.hstatus_id = s.id
group by s.id, s.hiringstatus
```

I assume that the table `hStatus_table` is like this:

```
| ID  | HiringStatus  |
| --- | ------------- |
| 1   | Hired         |
| 2   | Qualified     |
| 3   | Near Hire     |
| 4   | Not Qualified |
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jUKYThmVTmpRBi5mgcfct1/2).
Results:

```
| hiringstatus  | counter |
| ------------- | ------- |
| Hired         | 3       |
| Qualified     | 0       |
| Near Hire     | 1       |
| Not Qualified | 0       |
```

Comment: Thank you. But what does "S" in s.hiringstatus mean and "T" in t.jobseekerid?

Comment: `s` is the alias of the table `hStatus_table` and `t` is the alias of the subquery.

Comment: ahh It worked man. thank you so much! been working on this for a whole day already

Comment: I know the question was already answered, but how do you do it if that
I have another column "job_location" which would only be "Local" or "Overseas" how do I count only the location of the highest hiring status

[link](https://imgur.com/a/4n1nGi2)

Duplication is allowed but only if let say I was HIRED by two different employers one from overseas and one from Local.



Do I need to ask a new question for this? sorry, new to stackoverflow.

Comment: This is a new requirement so you must post sample data and expected results and explain what you want in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select hiring_status, sum(seqnum = 1)
from (select js.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Jobseeker_id order by hiring_status desc) as seqnum
      from jobseekers js
     ) js
group by hiring_status;
```

This assumes that `hiring_status` is either a number or a string that starts with the appropriate digits.

It also assumes that all `hiring_status` values are in `jobseekers`.

EDIT:

If the ids are stored in another table, then you would simply use a `left join`:

```
select hs.*, count(js.job_seeker)
from hstatus_table hs left join
     (select js.job_seeker, max(hs.hiring_status_id) as max_hiring_status_id
      from jobseekers js
      group by js.job_seeker
     ) js
     on hs.hiring_status_id = max_hiring_status_id
group by hs.hiring_status_id;
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a little new to this and I don't know which one to substitute so
Jobseeker_Id is linked to a table name "jobseeker_table" and
Employer_Id is also linked to another table "employer_table" and
lastly Hstatus_id is linked to another table named "Hstatus_table"